# How to change the state of a Spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

All my "Completed Applications" are in a FINISHED "State" in the Spark UI. Even when my "Completed Driver" is in a FAILED "State" (because in the scala code I do a `System.exit(1)` in case of any exceptions), its associated "Completed Application" is in a FINISHED "State".

I would like to be able in the scala code to change the State of my application into a FAILED State. Note I know how to change the State of the driver, I do not know how to change the State of its application. Any suggestion how to achieve this?

I use Spark-1.6.1 and Spark-2.1.0 in Standalone mode. I use scala.